Is it important to account for transient voltage when designing an electric circuit?
I've been learning basic electronics lately (I have some high level understanding, and basic electromagnetism knowledge, but never got too deep into the details before).
I got curious about the concept of "initial transient", i.e. what happens in a circuit before it reaches a steady state/normal operation mode.
TLDR of my lengthy question: if an electronic component is rated for a certain max voltage, do we need to take into the account initial transient when designing a circuit? Since the voltages involved might be higher than the steady state voltages.
A concrete example
Let's say we have:

an ideal V_S = 5V DC voltage source with a switch
a LED with V_b = 7V reverse breakdown voltage connected to the switch over 1m wires

We connect the LED to the voltage source in reverse.

In the steady state, this shouldn't be a problem since 5V < 7V of reverse breakdown voltage.
Now, consider the initial transient moment (first few nanoseconds) after we close the switch, and when the EM field starts propagating over the wires from the voltage source.

initially the signal is propagating over the wires
after 1/c (speed of light) seconds the signal reaches reaches the diode "body".
it "sees" infinite resistance, so it's going to get fully reflected back onto the voltage source

As it's a full reflection, for a brief moment there would be double the voltage across the diode's terminals, i.e. 2 * V_S = 10V, which is bigger than the reverse breakdown voltage V_b = 7V.
(note -- the signal here is essentially a square wave, so different frequency components would propagate at different speed, but hopefully we can still analyse the max amplitude which would be 2x? And perhaps this would be close to the true value since the wire is short)
Question: wouldn't that damage the LED? E.g. let's say it's not a Zener diode, but just a regular LED that's not meant to conduct current in reverse.

if yes, is this a real effect that we need to take into the consideration when constructing real circuits?
does this also apply to other components that are rated for a certain voltage (e.g. transistors/integrated circuits etc)?
or does the voltage rating really only apply to a "sustained" voltage, and it's not a problem if this only happens for a brief moment during initial transient?

Simulation on falstad
To validate my reasoning, I experimented with a circuit on falstad.
Here's the link to my setup.

I believe regular wires have zero length on falstad, so to simulate the delay of signal propagation and reflection from the load, I used the "transmission line" primitive.

on the left, there is a V_S = 5V battery
the transmission line has signal delay of 30 ns and 75 Ohm impedance (not that exact values matter since I'm interested in qualitative effects)

I also added a 1 Ohm series resistor to simulate normal resistance of the wires, since you can't configure it for transmission line on falstad. If we don't add the resistor, the transmission line behaves as LC circuit, so the signal never dies which makes a bit annoying to double check the steady state.


the device on the right is a diode. Forward voltage is 0.8V (default), reverse breakdown voltage is modified to V_b which I'll vary

Now, I did the following experiments.
In each experiment, I reset the simulation, which resets the time to 0ns.

set reverse breakdown voltage V_b to a low value, such that V_b < V_S. For instance, V_b = 2V.

Result: once the signal from battery propagates to diode (30ns, the transmission line delay), this results in voltage drop and some current over the diode, as expected (-103mA).

set reverse breakdown voltage to a high value, such that V_b > 2 * V_S, e.g. 11V.
Result:

after 30ns that takes the transmission line to propagate the signal from the battery, the signal is reflected completely off the diode, with no current passing through it -- as if it was an open circuit/infinite load. This makes sense.
the signal keeps sloshing back and forth in the transmission line -- it acts as RLC contour
eventually (after tens of microseconds), 5V settles on the diode, still with no current passing. The current in the rest of the circuit dies down (the signal is dissipated through the resistor.


set reverse breakdown voltage to an intermediate value, such that V_S < V_b < 2 * V_S. For instance, V_b = 7V.


Plot of current (yellow line) and voltage (greyed out line) on diode, over time. Each time division is 20ns.

Now things are more interesting:

after the signal reaches the diode (after 30ns), there is a 7V voltage drop over the diode, and some current (yellow line, -37mA).
at 90ns mark, the signal does a roundtrip back and forth over the transmission line, and voltage over the diode is -5.7V. This isn't enough to break it down anymore and the current over it stops
after that the situation is identical to case 2 -- the diode is not passing the signal and the rest of the contour is RLC -- after some microseconds the current in the circuit fizzles out.

So this case 3 is the situation I was asking about, and to me it confirms that it could be indeed problematic in the real world?

An incredible video that seems relevant to your thoughts process: Watch electricity hit a fork ...

Your concrete example is poor. An LED will have a reverse bias junction capacitance of up to several tens of pF.

Also, the 60-ns pulse of current delivers 7 V * 37.55 mA = 263 mW of power to the LED, for a total energy of 263 mW * 60 ns = 16 nJ. This is far too little energy to do any damage to the LED. Even in high-reliablity applications, we consider any transient of less than 1 uJ to be too small to worry about.

@Attie thanks! Yeah, I went down the rabbit hole of watching all these videos analyzing initial EM propagation (sadly this seems to be always omitted from the textbooks!).
However, didn't find anything discussing dielectric breakdown or component breakdown on microscopic/short timescale level.
Was even considering trying to set up a field solver myself, but never done this before, and it seems like a proper project, so figured falstad is a good start

Your question is a tricky one. It depends on how the manufacturer of a LED component defines the rated voltage. And it depends on safety margins, too.
If you consider a 5V battery supply, it will usually have some noise (e.g. white noise) overlayed. This noise has a statistical nature, which means that it can reach any voltage if you just observe it long enough.
So in theory, there is no such thing as safety when it comes to rated voltage. But we are lucky: The world is a practical place and your LED circuit does not need to run 100 million years :-)
The manufacturer specifies the voltage rating by using a variable voltage, tests the component for damage and applies a safety margin.
Most component failure modes are related to energy, which means they do not break if voltage is exceeded over a very short period of time. This is the case for your simulated reflection, so the short time 10V amplitude should not do any harm, because it is very short and does not provide much energy.
Take for example the ESD protection diodes that most IC's have at their inputs. They have a maximum voltage rating, but you can supply a higher voltage if you manage to limit the current to much less than 1mA.
My final statement here is that you are always safe if you are below the rated voltage and you might be unsafe above that. In this case, you might want to do some own reliability testing of your circuit.

Thanks! White noise is actually a very good point, makes sense.

Most component failure modes are related to energy

To be precise, would it be power? I.e. a LED can pass a lot of energy over its lifetime if it's constantly on under 5V, but what matters is how much extra energy it can dissipate in a unit of time if it's exceeded?

Does it basically mean:

breakdown voltage is the minimum threshold where things will be fine
past breakdown voltage threshold, there may be some current which may or may not damage your component depending on specifics of the construction. E.g. it may start to leak reverse current, but the power/heat is small enough for it to dissipate and reach thermal equilibrium so it wouldn't do irreversible damage to the diode (reverse current might still be a problem for the rest of the circuit)
if the voltage is even higher/sustained for longer, this will damage the np junction/melt diode


Your comments seem OK to me. Yes, power failure mode would be more precise.


TLDR of my lengthy question: if an electronic component is rated for a certain max voltage, do we need to take into the account initial transient when designing a circuit? Since the voltages involved might be higher than the steady-state voltages.

As one CIA agent said, If you are on time, you are late, so you always plan on arriving early if you have been told, you're fired if ever late.
If you understand the analogy, if you design to the absolute maximum and allow some exception to the possible state that exceeds that, then you are risking failure. This shouldn't change your attitude even if you experience many samples that only leak 10 uA at -7V when rated something for -5V as there is a design margin for temp. rise and batch variations.
I had this experience with a client to whom, I supplied over 100k/yr of 5mm LEDs that were starting to see 1% field failures. I took it upon myself to visit the factory in NZ and found a dozen violations of ESD, soldering and injected plastic moulding. ESD wounding may not cause an immediate failure but will cause early field failures. It can easily be detected by an increase in junction capacitance when turned off. Since all LEDs were 100% faactory tested and sorted to 1% tolerance for me, I was certain none of the LEDs were defective.
After supplying a list of Corrective Actions to their Mfg. Process, I changed the design of the LEDs I specified /purchased to include ESD protection (reverse diodes) immediately for the next and all types of following shipments. Then I went for 2 wks holiday driving around Jurassic Park and sightseeing golf courses and tropical beaches.
